Understanding scenario where there are two SharePoint search servers
I have been given task to prepare 2x SharePoint Search servers. In case of one SharePoint search server, it is easy as you just select Search server role while installing which will start relevant search services on server and stop other services. Then you go ahead and create a new search service application.
Is it the same in case of two search servers? What I understand that it will work as follows:

Install SharePoint on both machines and select Search Server role when you run SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard
Create one search service application
On both servers keep index location same for e.g. D:\SPIndex

That's it? Do we need to configure load balancer or something? I assume these steps above will suffice and if one server goes down, then other server will be able to handle requests.
Is my understanding correct?

I would recommend reviewing MS Documents on Search Architecture for Small Farm at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/plan-enterprise-search-architecture
